# Splitting quantity of products on to new rows on the cart page of woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following code to split products that have a quantity higher than 1 in to seperate rows.

However, if i add 5 of the same product for example, it lags and takes a long time and often gives a 502 bad gateway error because the ajax is cycling through the code for every product.

I am wondering if instead of running the function on add to cart being pushed, i can just replicate the function for when the user actually goes on to the cart page, that way the ajax cart wont show every single product, it will just show for example `product A - 100`

rather than showing 100 of them. I'd want to just show 100 of them each 1 on a row on the cart page.

This is the code im currently using

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 
    'mai_split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items', 10, 6 );


function mai_split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items( 
        $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, 
        $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) 
{

    // If product has more than 1 quantity
    if ( $quantity > 1 ) {
        // Keep the product but set its quantity to 1
        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, 1 );

        // Run a loop 1 less than the total quantity
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $quantity -1; $i++ ) {
            /**
            * Set a unique key.
            * This is what actually forces the product into its own cart line item
            */
            $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() . "Hi Mom" );

            // Add the product as a new line item with the same variations that were passed
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: This was some code that i found on stack overflow last week and have been using, thanks for the advice, i shall check the link now.

Comment: If you did this only when the user actually visits the cart page - then you would still create your order line items at that point then, meaning if the user goes back to the shop and puts another product in the cart, then the cart display loaded via AJAX will still contain all those lines.

Comment: I see, so there is no alternative ? i just cant run a website that takes 25 minutes to add 100 products, and then also freezes cause the max execution time is 60 seconds. Need it to happen instantly

Answer (score 0):

You are in an endless loop. The WC()->cart->add_to_cart method triggers the 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' action hook which your function attached to.

You can find some details here: https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_hook/woocommerce_add_to_cart/

Quick fix would be to extend the if statement with an additional check:

```
if ( !isset($cart_item_data['unique_key']) && $quantity > 1 ) {
 ... 
}
```